# Big problems installing Playonlinux

Tags: playonlinux

I was trying to install playonlinux since I needed an app based on Windows.
I first runned sudo apt-get update and then sudo apt-get install playonlinux.
It started running and began to remove a lot of things like gnome controllers, drivers and other things.
Then it suddenly stopped and said the process stopped before finish.
Now I don't have Wifi, I can't access Settings, can't access my folders because there's no folder icon.
I'm really worried and don't know what to do.
Please, I need help. I don't wanna lose all of my data and programs. I want my machine to work again.

EDIT: I'm working on Ubuntu 21.10 Desktop. My computer has a dual-boot.
The commands I runned were:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

I don't have the output since the terminal shut down.
When I run

```
apt-cache policy playonlinux
```

This outputs:

> playonlinux:
> Installed: 4.3.4-2
> Candidate: 4.3.4-2
> Version table:
> *** 4.3.2-2 500
> 500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/multiverse amd6
> 4 Packages
> 500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/multiverse i386
> Packages
> 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Maybe it was a stupid idea, but I shut down the machine and now I can't reinitiate Ubuntu.

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details which are the starting point. You should also copy/paste your commands & resultant output into your question so we can fully appreciate your issue & thus help you to solve it.  Currently it seems you've *likley* applied inappropriate commands/sources to your *unstated* product/release thus the problems; but we're guessing due to lack of detail.  FYI:  Most Ubuntu products allow you to re-install without losing any data; but you've provided no specifics as to Ubuntu product/release

Comment: Thanks, I added some of the info. But I don't have the output cause the terminal closed.

Comment: The output should exist in logs (`/var/log/apt/history.log`) but the output of `apt-cache policy playonlinux` may suffice (*letting us know what sources you've added that may have created the issue*)  FYI:  Being specific as to the Ubuntu 21.10 product is also helpful; I assume Ubuntu 21.10 Desktop & not 21.10 Server

Comment: Yes, it's desktop.

Comment: I added the info you were asking for. Can't copy paste cause I have no Internet. But I'm really grateful for your help.

Comment: For future reference, after you typed the `sudo apt-get install playonlinux`, the system shows you what packages will be added and removed, and you have to agree to it and proceed by typing `y`. This is the point at which you can stop before destroying your system.

Comment: If you can connect to internet, then run `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`. If you cannot, consider fresh installing Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Remove all of PlayOnLinux and install the `wine` command that is a great alternative to install and run any Windows app, here is my explanation : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437380/ubuntu-22-04-how-to-run-an-exe-file-by-the-desktop-shortcut